# Trouble with a stack based algorithm

Tags: algorithm, stack

I'm working on this programming assignment. It tests our understanding of stacks and their applications. I find it extremely difficult to come up with an algorithm that can work *efficiently* and *accurately*. Some of their test cases have 200,000+ "trees"! While my algorithm can work for simpler test cases with less than 10 trees, it failed in the accuracy and efficiency departments when the number of "trees" is exceedingly large (from 100+ onwards).

I would appreciate it very much, if you guys can kindly give me a hint or point me to the right direction. Thank you.

> Task Statement
>
> Monkeys like to swing from tree to tree. They can swing from one tree
>   to another directly as long as there is no tree in between that is
>   taller than or have the same height as either one of the two trees.
>   For example, if there are 5 trees with heights 19m, 17m, 20m, 20m and
>   20m lining up in that order, then the monkey will be able to swing
>   from one tree to the other as shown below:
>
> ```
> 1. from first tree to second tree
> 2. from first tree to third tree
> 3. from second tree to third tree
> 4. from third tree to fourth tree
> 5. from fourth tree to fifth tree
> ```
>
> Tarzan, the king of jungle who is able to communicate with the
>   monkeys, wants to test the monkeys to see if they know how to count
>   the total number of pairs of trees that they can swing directly from
>   one to the other. But he himself is not very good in counting. So he
>   turns to you, the best Java programmer in the country, to write a
>   program for getting the correct count for the trees in different parts
>   of the jungle.
>
> Input
>
> The first line contains N, the number of trees in the path. The next
>   line contains N integers a1 a2 a3 ... aN, where ai represents the
>   height of the i-th tree in the path, 0 < ai ≤ 231 and 2 ≤ N ≤ 500,000.
>
> Note that short symbol N is used above for convenience. In your
>   program, you are expected to give it a descriptive name.
>
> Output
>
> The total number of pairs of trees which the monkeys can swing
>   directly from one to the other with the given list of tree heights.
>
> Sample Input 1
>
> 4
>
> 3 4 1 2
>
> Sample Output 1
>
> 4
>
> Sample Input 2
>
> 5
>
> 19 17 20 20 20
>
> Sample Output 2
>
> 5
>
> Sample Input 3
>
> 4 1
>
> 2 21 21 12
>
> Sample Output 3
>
> 3

Here's my code. So this is a method that returns the number of pairs of trees a monkey can swing with. The parameter is an array of inputs.

**My algorithm goes as follows:**

we set the numPairs to be (array length - 1), since all trees can be swing from one to another.

now we find the extra numPairs (extra trees to swing with).

push the first input into the empty stack

**we enter a for loop:**

for the next input until the end of array:

**case1:**

if the top of the stack is smaller than the current input and the size of the stack is equal to 1, then we replace the top with the input.

**case2:**

if the top of the stack smaller than the current input and the size of the stack is bigger than 1, we pop the top, and enter a while loop to pop the previous elements which is smaller than the current top of the stack.

we then push the current input after we exit the while loop.

**case3:**

otherwise, if the above conditions are not satisfied, we simply push the current input into the stack.

**we exit the for loop**

return the numPairs

public int solve(int[] arr) {

```
    int input, temp;
    numPairs = arr.length-1;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        input = arr[i];

        if(stack.isEmpty())
            stack.push(input);

        else if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            if(input>stack.peek() && stack.size() == 1)
            {
                stack.pop();
                stack.push(input);
            }
            else if(input>stack.peek() && stack.size() > 1)
            {
                temp = stack.pop();
                while(!stack.isEmpty() && temp < stack.peek())
                {
                    numPairs++;
                    temp = stack.pop();
                }
                stack.push(input);
                //numPairs++;
            }
            else
                stack.push(input);
        }
    }
    return numPairs;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip with java development, try not to nest your condition too much, could also speed it up by making it more recursive (divide and conquer).

Comment: Also your current approach isn't greedy, the reason why its crashing when you exceed 100+ trees is because you are trying to brute force every possible path (O(n^2)), if you make it recursive you could push for O(log(n)) complexity.

Comment: Mmm.. got that, nesting is bad habit of mine. I'm new to recursion though, it fries my brain just by thinking about it... Is there any simpler iterative based solutions?

Comment: recursion isn't as bad as you think, you just need a point to where it will finish (its hard because, you can't really debug as you would when you think linear).

Comment: mind uploading the PDF, and maybe some sample code? of the assignment and I'll see if I can mock something up.

Comment: Sure.. but how do I upload?

Comment: try [rapidshare](https://rapidshare.com/)

Comment: I will try rapidshare. Do you have dropbox?

Comment: Anyway here is it: http://rapidshare.com/files/3567429428/lab4ex1.zip

Comment: I'm not sure about rapidshare download permission. Will add you thru skype and send you the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution, it's an iterative one.

```
class Result {

  // declare the member field
  Stack<Integer> stack;
  int numPairs = 0;
  // declare the constructor
  public Result()
  {
    stack = new Stack<Integer>();
  }


  /* 
   * solve   : to compute the result, return the result
   *  Pre-condition : parameter must be of array of integer type
   * Post-condition : return the number of tree pairs that can be swung with
   */
  public int solve(int[] arr) {
    // implementation
    int input;

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
      input = arr[i];
      if(stack.isEmpty()) //if stack is empty, just push the input
        stack.push(input);

      else if(!stack.isEmpty())
      {
        //do a while loop to pop all possible top stack element until 
        //the top element is bigger than the input
        //or the stack is empty
        while(!stack.isEmpty() && input > stack.peek()) 
        {
          stack.pop();
          numPairs++;
        }

        //if the stack is empty after exiting the while loop
        //push the current element onto the stack
        if(stack.isEmpty())
          stack.push(input);
        //this condition applies for two cases:
        //1. the while loop is never entered because the input is smaller than the top element by default
        //2. the while loop is exited and the input is pushed onto the non-empty stack with numPairs being incremented 
        else if(!stack.isEmpty() && input < stack.peek())
        {
          stack.push(input);
          numPairs++;
        }
        //this is the last condition:
        //the input is never pushed if the input is identical to the top element
        //instead we increment the numPairs
        else if(input == stack.peek())
          numPairs++;

      }

    }
    return numPairs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, there are two kinds of trees accessible to each other:

1. Trees that are next to each (adjacent) other are always accessible to each other
2. Trees that are not adjacent are only accessible if all the trees in between are shorter than both of the trees.

One might come up with several types of solutions for this:

- The brute force solution: compare every tree to every other tree checking the conditions above. Running time: O(n^2)
- Find near accessible neighbors solution: look for near neighbors that are accessible. Running time: close to O(n).  Here's how this would work:

Build an array of tree sizes in order that they are given.  Then walk this array in order and for every tree at index `i`:

**Going to the right from `i`**

1. If tree at `i+1` is taller then tree at `i` break out (no more accessible neighbors can be found)
2. Add `1` to the count of accessible trees if tree at `i+1` is shorter than tree at `i+2`
3. Do the same for trees `i+2`, `i+3`.. etc. until you find a tree that is taller than tree at `i`.

This will get a count of non-adjacent accessible trees for every tree. Then just add `N*2-2` to the count to account for all the adjacent trees, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I solved this yesterday, but it's good to know another method that works. :)

Comment: Awesome. Maybe you want to post your solution as well, esp. if it is a good one.